Keep row number or ID variable when viewing a dataframe
when working with dataframe in Rstudio viewer, I would like to see the number of the row or a certain variable (ID variable) always visible when scrolling to the right to view more variables. How is this this possible?

Stop using View() entirely. Better options are head(df[c('X77', 'X93')]), head(df[c('id', 'X77', 'X93')]), summary(df[c('id', 'X77', 'X93')]), subset(df, id %in% 1:10, select=c(id, X77, X93)) etc.

Currently, the View() function in R does not have the ability to show id when you scroll to the right
But if you really need it, you can duplicate the id column and put it in a later column order
